# merge json file and a php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hi all I have a json file like this:

```
[
   {
      "search":1,
      "hotelId":"YYB",
      "combination":"0|1|0|0|0|0",
   },
   {
      "search":1,
      "hotelId":"YYB",
      "combination":"0|1|0|0|0|0",
   },
   {
      "search":1,
      "hotelId":"YYW",
      "combination":"0|1|0|0|0|0",
   }
]
```

And I want to add to this json an array php converted into a json.

This is my php array

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(24) {
    ["search"]=>
    int(1)
    ["hotelId"]=>
    string(3) "rrr"
    ["combination"]=>
    string(11) "0|1|0|0|0|0"

  }
  [1]=>
  array(24) {
    ["search"]=>
    int(1)
    ["hotelId"]=>
    string(3) "ttt"
    ["combination"]=>
    string(11) "0|1|0|0|0|0"
}
```

I'm trying to add my encode php array to the json file.

This is what I have tried:

```
$filename = 'json_upload/rooms.json';
$result = fread($file2, filesize($filename));
$arr = $result;
$arr_ret_room = $room_arr; //my php array
$res = array_merge_recursive((array)$arr, (array)$arr_ret_room);
fwrite($file2,  json_encode($res));
fclose($file2);
```

I have also tried with `array_merge` the result doesn't change when I open the json file the script add me a new root element like this:

```
[
       {
          "search":1,
          "hotelId":"YYB",
          "combination":"0|1|0|0|0|0",
       },
       {
          "search":1,
          "hotelId":"YYB",
          "combination":"0|1|0|0|0|0",
       },
       {
          "search":1,
          "hotelId":"YYW",
          "combination":"0|1|0|0|0|0",
       }
    ]
[
       {
          "search":1,
          "hotelId":"rrr",
          "combination":"0|1|0|0|0|0",
       },
       {
          "search":1,
          "hotelId":"ttt",
          "combination":"0|1|0|0|0|0",
       }
    ]
```

Instead of this:

```
[
           {
              "search":1,
              "hotelId":"YYB",
              "combination":"0|1|0|0|0|0",
           },
           {
              "search":1,
              "hotelId":"YYB",
              "combination":"0|1|0|0|0|0",
           },
           {
              "search":1,
              "hotelId":"YYW",
              "combination":"0|1|0|0|0|0",
           },
           {
              "search":1,
              "hotelId":"rrr",
              "combination":"0|1|0|0|0|0",
           },
           {
              "search":1,
              "hotelId":"ttt",
              "combination":"0|1|0|0|0|0",
           }
        ]
```

How can I merge correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to convert JSON string to array then merge them instead of combining these JSON string. You need to change this:

```
    $arr = $result;
    $arr_ret_room = $room_arr; //my php array
    $res = array_merge_recursive((array)$arr, (array)$arr_ret_room);
    fwrite($file2,  json_encode($res));
    fclose($file2);
```

to

```
    $array1 = json_decode($result,true);
    $array2 = $arr_ret_room;
    $newArray = array_merge($array1,$array2);
    $newJSON = json_encode($newArray);
    fwrite($file2,  $newJSON); 
    fclose($file2);
```

Comment: return me error, array_merge first argument is not anarray, I have changed to this $newArray = array_merge((array)$array1, (array)$array2); but the original problem still exists

Comment: It means that variable `$result` is not a valid JSON string. You may need to check this carefully.

Comment: if I don't append anything the inital json is correct

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct:

```
// assuming that $file contains contents of json file

$arr = array(...); //your php array
$jsonArr = json_decode($file);

$result = $arr + $jsonArr;
```

then you can save your `$result` to your file.